# Stack Overflow Jobs page is blank after submitting a job application

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

Once I submit my application via Stack Overflow Jobs, I get a white empty message box overlayed on a black background with no way to exit (pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) or any intended buttons on the white message box like **Okay**. Please see the image below.

[image: Blank Image].

The only way to exit this screen is by **reloading** the page. I believe showing a blank overlay isn't the intention here!

Comment: Maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372267/messages-not-loading is related

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely happening because you have adblock on. Disable it and it should load fine after the submission.