# Messages not loading

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

One hour ago I received a notification that I had a new jobs message.  When I go to my inbox and click on the message, it says it is loading the message. However, it never loads. It is stuck on the loading message.

[image]

Comment: Are there errors in the JavaScript console? It may also be worth mentioning what browser you're using

Comment: @Filnor Thank you for the comment. I disabled uBlock Origin 1.16.14 and the messages loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had uBlock Origin 1.16.14 installed. Once I disabled it and refreshed the page, my StackOverflow messages loaded successfully.

Comment: It’s not only uBlock, it must be some specific rule. I also have uBlock v1.16.14, but job messages work for me just fine. You might want to re-enable uBlock and then check your dev console for JS or network errors.

Comment: AdBlockPlus in Chrome made for me same issue with freezing on message "Loading your message...". Disabling this plugin for StackOverflow was helpful there.